# How can i toggle between dark/light mode using a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

I want to toggle dark/light mode using a div.

```
<div theme="light" class="page login">
```

theme=light should be toggled to "dark" or "light" upon clicking the div.

```
<div theme="light" id="switch-theme" class="switch-btn">
```

This is the div that should toggle between the two modes when clicked.

I tried JS, but couldnt get it to work. anyone can advise me in the right direction?

Comment: Please attach your JS code for ease of getting help.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add a `<script>` tag for this, you can define this directly on the `onclick` event:

```js
this.setAttribute('theme', this.getAttribute('theme') === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark');
```

```css
[theme='light'] {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

[theme='dark'] {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div theme="light" id="switch-theme" class="switch-btn" onclick="this.setAttribute('theme', this.getAttribute('theme') === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark')">Lorum Ipsum</div>
```

But if your page has multiple instances of this element, you should register them properly:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('[theme]')].forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', switchTheme));

function switchTheme() {
  this.setAttribute('theme', this.getAttribute('theme') === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark');
}
```

```css
[theme='light'] {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

[theme='dark'] {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div theme="light" id="switch-theme" class="switch-btn">Lorum Ipsum</div>
<div theme="light" id="switch-theme" class="switch-btn">Lorum Ipsum</div>
<div theme="light" id="switch-theme" class="switch-btn">Lorum Ipsum</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the great answer! 
When i do this, it only toggles the button to dark, not every "theme" tag.
Any advice?